# IssuerSerial Matching in Pades Signature with IText 8.0.3

Tags: itext, digital-signature, bouncycastle, pades

I'm signing a pdf document with PdfPadesSigner's SignWithBaselineLTAProfile method in IText 8.0.3. I use my certificate in the USB token as ExternalSignature (pkcs11library). Everything is very simple. The only problem is that there is no IssuerSerial match in the signature structure. I can't solve this problem. Thank you from now.

```
var padesSigner = new PdfPadesSigner(new PdfReader(content.Document.Stream), signedStream);

IList<IX509Certificate> trusted = new List<IX509Certificate>();

        foreach (var crnCert in parameters.TrustedCertificates)
            trusted.Add(new X509CertificateBC(crnCert));

padesSigner.SetTrustedCertificates(trusted);

    TSAClientBouncyCastle timeStampInfo = null;

        if (parameters.TimeStampSettings != null)
            timeStampInfo = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(parameters.TimeStampSettings.HostUrl, parameters.TimeStampSettings.LoginId, parameters.TimeStampSettings.Password);

  var certificates = new IX509Certificate[]
        {
            new X509CertificateBC(parameters.SigningCertificate)
        };

padesSigner.SignWithBaselineLTAProfile(properties, certificates, this, timeStampInfo);
```

**Must be;**

```
<RelatedCertificate Certificate="CERTIFICATE_FATİH-POLAT_20231017-0920">
                     <Origin>SIGNED_DATA</Origin>
                     <Origin>DSS_DICTIONARY</Origin>
                     <Origin>VRI_DICTIONARY</Origin>
                     <CertificateRef>
                         <Origin>SIGNING_CERTIFICATE</Origin>
                         **<IssuerSerial match="true">MIIBAzCB86SB8DCB7TELMAKGI....</IssuerSerial>**
                         <DigestAlgoAndValue match="true">
                             <DigestMethod>SHA256</DigestMethod>
                             <DigestValue>Fuxst8SamhghugBDp/6FD+kzENHiYzqEyKOXaFZL2jc=</DigestValue>
                         </DigestAlgoAndValue>
                     </CertificateRef>
                 </RelatedCertificate>
```

**What i have;**

```
<RelatedCertificate Certificate="CERTIFICATE_FATİH-POLAT_20231017-0920">
                    <Origin>SIGNED_DATA</Origin>
                    <Origin>DSS_DICTIONARY</Origin>
                    <Origin>VRI_DICTIONARY</Origin>
                    <CertificateRef>
                        <Origin>SIGNING_CERTIFICATE</Origin>
                        <DigestAlgoAndValue match="true">
                            <DigestMethod>SHA256</DigestMethod>
                            <DigestValue>Fuxst8SamhghugBDp/6FD+kzENHiYzqEyKOXaFZL2jc=</DigestValue>
                        </DigestAlgoAndValue>
                    </CertificateRef>
                </RelatedCertificate>
```

Comment: Why do you think there needs to be a `IssuerSerial` element there?

Comment: I used my signature in another application and the resulting signature has this value. I found out that this is used to verify signatures.

Comment: Can you share the PDF that in verification causes the "What i have;" output for analysis?

Comment: Here it is. Thanks. https://hizliyolla.com.tr/signed_LTA.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML excerpts you show appear to be diagnostic data generated by eSig DSS. Thus, I'll explain here what the missing entry means and why it is ok that it is missing.

#### What does this missing element indicate?

That `CertificateRef` element inside the `RelatedCertificate` here indicates that the certificate is referenced as signer certificate from a `signingCertificateV2` signed attribute of the signature.

The value of that attribute is specified in RFC 5035 as

```asn1
SigningCertificateV2 ::=  SEQUENCE {
    certs        SEQUENCE OF ESSCertIDv2,
    policies     SEQUENCE OF PolicyInformation OPTIONAL
}

ESSCertIDv2 ::=  SEQUENCE {
    hashAlgorithm           AlgorithmIdentifier
           DEFAULT {algorithm id-sha256},
    certHash                 Hash,
    issuerSerial             IssuerSerial OPTIONAL
}

Hash ::= OCTET STRING

IssuerSerial ::= SEQUENCE {
    issuer                   GeneralNames,
    serialNumber             CertificateSerialNumber
}
```

The `IssuerSerial` element inside the `CertificateRef` element you are missing in your iText created signatures refers to the `issuerSerial` member of the `ESSCertIDv2` in the attribute value.

As you can already see in the definition, this `issuerSerial` member is marked `OPTIONAL`.

Thus, the observation that the `IssuerSerial` element is missing shows that iText makes use of that `OPTIONAL`ity and does not include a `issuerSerial` member in the `signingCertificateV2` attribute.

#### Is it ok that iText does not include a `issuerSerial` here?

First of all, as remarked above, according to RFC 5035 the element is optional, **so any signature processor (e.g. a validator) must expect signatures to not include a `issuerSerial` member in their `signingCertificateV2` attribute**.

But do the specifications in question go into more detail on this?

RFC 5035 says

> The first certificate identified in the
> sequence of certificate identifiers MUST be the certificate used
> to verify the signature.  The encoding of the ESSCertIDv2 for this
> certificate SHOULD include the issuerSerial field.

I.e. it *recommends* inclusion of the field which at first glance would make iText's decision not to do so look inappropriate.

But RFC 5035 here is used in the context of a CAdES signature container in a PAdES signature, so the CAdES and PAdES specification may modify this recommendation.

The CAdES specification (ETSI EN 319 122-1) says

> The information in the IssuerSerial element is only a hint that can help to identify the certificate
> whose digest matches the value present in the reference. But the binding information is the digest of the
> certificate.

*(section 5.2.2.3 "ESS `signing-certificate-v2` attribute")*

Furthermore, in the requirements for baseline profiles, that specification even says

> The `issuerSerial` field should not be included

*(section 6.3 "Requirements on components and services", "Additional requirements", item g)*

The PAdES specification (ETSI EN 319 142-1) here merely says

> Generators shall use either the signing certificate or the signing-certificate-v2 attribute, depending on the hash
> function, in accordance with ETSI EN 319 122-1

Thus, taken all together **the `issuerSerial` member is optional and its use, if anything, is not recommended.**

#### What does this mean in your case?

The signatures you create with *PdfPadesSigner's SignWithBaselineLTAProfile method in IText 8.0.3* are good, at least in respect to the aspect we discussed here, and the excerpt you called a "Must be" actually only is a "Can be" or even a "Should not be".

Also your comment "I found out that this is used to verify signatures" indicates that the verifier who told you so does not correctly handle the attribute in question, in particular not in the context of PAdES signatures.

#### An aside: an error in the time stamps in your example

The time stamps (both the signature time stamp and the document time stamp) incorrectly encode their signed attributes: The `signingCertificateV2` attribute in them is encoded like this:

```asn1
SEQUENCE (2 elem)
  OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.47 signingCertificateV2 (S/MIME Authenticated Attributes)
  SET (1 elem)
    SEQUENCE (1 elem)
      SEQUENCE (1 elem)
        SEQUENCE (2 elem)
          SEQUENCE (2 elem)
            OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 sha-256 (NIST Algorithm)
            NULL
          OCTET STRING (32 byte) 2E8EFCDD4C13BCB9F18E2AAD1A5391EEF0415D041171794C51EBD9BB8C5E23EE
```

The signed attributes must be DER encoded. DER encoding in particular means that DEFAULT values are *not* included.

The hash algorithm SHA-256 indicated there in your time stamps *is* the default value (see my quote from RFC 5035 above), so the encoding above is erroneous.

(Not many validators actually *check* the DER encoding of the signed attributes in this depth, but some do. In the recent ETSI plug test the software of at least one participant did check this. Thus, with those time stamps your signatures may often be accepted but sometimes suddenly not.)

By the way, these `signingCertificateV2` attributes in your time stamps also don't include the optional `issuerSerial` member... ;)

Comment: This is a very informative answer. Thank you. When an application called Imzager verifies the signature on the pdf I sent you, it gives the result "Valid but Incomplete". I won't mind this OPTIONAL element anymore.

So how can I fix these errors in timestamps? After all, I'm just providing access information.

Comment: *"When an application called Imzager verifies the signature on the pdf I sent you, it gives the result "Valid but Incomplete"."* - Hhmmm, that application should give a more detailed report to become useful. Is that app made for validating PAdES baseline signatures? Or does it expect different signatures profiles? It might be made for validating first generation PAdES signatures e.g. PAdES E-EPEL signatures. In that case a custom signature policy entry would be missing. But without further information, we can only guess...

Comment: *"So how can I fix these errors in timestamps? After all, I'm just providing access information."* - in that case you can only inform the TSA that their timestamp creation service creates broken time stamps, and ask them to fix that.

Comment: The primary target of this application appears to be CAdES. Maybe that's why an update regarding the PAdES signature has been missing. Thank you for your support.